# Problem about Ito isometry

Tags: stochastic-calculus

The following question is from my professor, I have no clue about it at all.

> Let $(W (t))_{t\geq0}$ denote a standard Brownian motion. Consider a
> model of asset price given as
>
> $$\mathrm{d} S(t)=\mu S(t) \mathrm{d} t+\sigma(t) S(t) \mathrm{d}
>  W(t), \quad S(0)=s_{0}$$
>
> where $\mu > 0$ is a constant and $\sigma(t)>0$ is a deterministic
> (non-random) function of time. Ito's isometry tell us that
> $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t} f(s, W(s)) \mathrm{d}
> W(s)\right)^{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{t} \mathbb{E}\left[f^{2}(s,W(s))\right] \mathrm{d} s$  for a square integrable function f.
>
> a). Using Itô’s isometry, compute the mean and variance of
> $\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(s) \mathrm{d} W(s)$.
>
> b). Compute the mean of S(T).

For part (a), can I use the following process:

Let $Z(t)=\sigma(s)dW(s)$, $Z(t)$ is a martingale so
$$\mathbb{E}(\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(s) \mathrm{d} W(s))=0$$

Moreover, based on the Ito's isometry,
$$Var(Z(t))=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(s) \mathrm{d} W(s)\right)^2=\int_{0}^{t} \mathbb{E}\left[\sigma(s)^2\right] \mathrm{d} s=?$$

I am stuck here.

Comment: You might be overthinking it. We are given that $\sigma(t)$ is a *deterministic* function of time. Therefore the expectation of $\sigma$ is merely itself and so the variance is $\int_0^t \sigma(s)^2 ds$.

Comment: Do you mean   $Z(t) = \int_0^t σ(u) dW_u $? If yes, then what you wrote so far is correct: $(Z(t))_{t \geq 0}$ is indeed a martingale since $σ(\cdot)$ is deterministic. To finish part a), observe that  $ \mathbb E [σ(s)^2]= σ(s)^2$ since $σ(\cdot)$ is deterministic. Thus the integral becomes $ \int_0^t σ^2(s) ds. $

Do you have any more information for b)? Perhaps that $S(t)$ is an Ito process so that you can use Ito's formula?